# Quiz App using flutter dart and api, Could not find correct Provider

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-web

I am a newbie trying to create an app for my webapp. I am exposing my data using API and rendering it in my app. My webapp returns a bunch of MCQs. I want to be able to show this as a quiz on my app. Kindly let me know if you have any questions. Here is my QuizPlay.dart

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:someapp/api/api.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
//import 'package:someapp/widget/widget.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

class QuizPlay extends StatefulWidget{
  @override
  _QuizPlayState createState() => _QuizPlayState();

}

class _QuizPlayState extends State<QuizPlay>{

  bool _isLoading = false;
  int _selectedValue;
  String optionSelected = "";
  int value;
  String _error;

  int ind;
  int _questionId=0;
  String _incorrectQuestion;

  @override
  void initState(){

    _selectedValue=0;
    _incorrectQuestion=" ";
    value=0;
    ind=0;
    super.initState();
  }


  void startTimer() {
    // Start the periodic timer which prints something after 5 seconds and then stop it .

    Timer timer = new Timer.periodic(new Duration(seconds: 5), (time) {
      print('Something');
      time.cancel();
    });
  }

  submitQuiz() async {
    startTimer();
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    String qorder= '8,9,10';
    String qlist ='8,9,10';
    String _incorrectques ='';
    String score ='20';
    String complete = "false";
    String user_ans = '{}';
   // DateTime endtime = new DateTime.now();
    String userid= "32";
    String quizid="2";

    Map data =      {
        'question_order': qorder,
        'question_list': qlist,
        'incorrect_questions': ' ',
        'current_score': score,
        'complete': complete,
        'user_answers': user_ans,
        'end': "2020-09-28 12:29:59",
        'user': userid,
        'quiz': quizid
      };

   print(data);
    var jsonResponse ;
    var response = await http.post("http://10.0.2.2:8000/apis/v1/sitting/", body: data);
    print(response.body);
    if(response.statusCode == 200) {
      jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body);
      if(jsonResponse != null) {
        setState(() {
          _isLoading = false;
        });
        print(response.body);
        sharedPreferences.setString("token", jsonResponse['token']);
       // Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => Home()), (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
      }
    }
    else {
      setState(() {
        _isLoading = false;
        _error = "Invalid Username and or Password.";
      });

    }
  }

  void nextQuestion(){
    _isLoading = true;
    setState(() {
      _questionId=_questionId+1;
      if (_questionId==3){
        _questionId=0;
      }
    });
  }

    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      //final quizP = Provider.of<QuizProvider>(context);
      return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Home"),
          brightness: Brightness.light,
          elevation: 0.5,
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          //brightness: Brightness.li,
        ),
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Container(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                        child: Container(

                          child: QuestionTile( questionID: _questionId),
                        )
                    ),
                RaisedButton(
                  onPressed: nextQuestion,
                  //onPressed: _signOut,

                  color: Colors.blueAccent,
                  child: Text(
                    "Next",
                  )
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
}

// ignore: must_be_immutable
class QuestionTile extends StatefulWidget {
  final int questionID;

  QuestionTile({Key key, this.questionID}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _QuestionTileState createState() => _QuestionTileState(questionID);

}

class _QuestionTileState extends State<QuestionTile> {
  final int questionID;

  _QuestionTileState(this.questionID);
  int _selectedValue;

  //int value;
  int ind;


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final quizP = Provider.of<QuizProvider>(context);
    //print(widget.questionID);
    //print(incorrectQuestion);
   /* return widget.questionID <quizP
        ? Container(
        child: Center(child: Text("Opps , Looks like we don't have any questions"),),):*/
    return Container(child: Column(
      children:<Widget> [
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 25.0, top: 120.0, bottom: 10.0),
          child: Row(
            children: [
              Column(
                children: [
                  Text("Q${widget.questionID+1}:   "+quizP.quizzes[0].getQuestions[widget.questionID].content,
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,fontSize: 20,)
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        quizP.quizzes[0].getQuestions.length == null
            ? Container(
          child: Center(child: Text("Opps , Looks like we don't have any questions"),),
        )
            : ListView.builder(
          itemCount: quizP.quizzes[0].getQuestions[widget.questionID].getanswers.length,
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemBuilder: (context, itemCount) {
            return RadioListTile(
              value: quizP.quizzes[0].getQuestions[widget.questionID].getanswers[itemCount].id,
              groupValue: _selectedValue,
              onChanged: (answer){

                setState(() {
                  _selectedValue = answer;
                 // if(quizP.quizzes[0].getQuestions[widget.questionID].getanswers[itemCount].correct== false){
                  _selectedValue = _selectedValue+1;
                     // _incorrectQuestion = 'hi';//quizP.quizzes[0].getQuestions[widget.questionID].id.toString();

                 // }
                });
              },
              title: Text("${ quizP.quizzes[0].getQuestions[widget.questionID].getanswers[itemCount].content}"),

            );
          },
        ),
      ],

    ),
    );
  }
}
```

My api.dart

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:someapp/models/quiz.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;


class QuizProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  QuizProvider() {
    this.fetchTasks();
  }

  List<Quiz> _quizzes = [];

  List<Quiz> get quizzes {
    return [..._quizzes];
  }
  fetchTasks() async {
    final url = 'http://10.0.2.2:8000/apis/v1/quiz/CL008/Physics/178?format=json';
    final response = await http.get(url);
    print(response.statusCode);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var data = json.decode(response.body) as List;
      _quizzes = data.map<Quiz>((json) => Quiz.fromJson(json)).toList();
      http.Response response1 = await http.get(Uri.encodeFull(url));

      print(_quizzes[0].getQuestions.length);
      notifyListeners();
    }
  }
}
```

and my quiz.dart

```
import 'dart:convert';

Quiz quizFromJson(String str) => Quiz.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String quizToJson(Quiz data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class Quiz {
  Quiz({
    this.id,
    this.title,
    this.description,
    this.url,
    this.category,
    this.randomOrder,
    this.passMark,
    this.draft,
    this.durationtest,
    this.getQuestions,
  });

  int id;
  String title;
  String description;
  String url;
  int category;
  bool randomOrder;
  int passMark;
  bool draft;
  String durationtest;
  List<GetQuestion> getQuestions;

  factory Quiz.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Quiz(
    id: json["id"],
    title: json["title"],
    description: json["description"],
    url: json["url"],
    category: json["category"],
    randomOrder: json["random_order"],
    passMark: json["pass_mark"],
    draft: json["draft"],
    durationtest: json["durationtest"],
    getQuestions: List<GetQuestion>.from(json["get_questions"].map((x) => GetQuestion.fromJson(x))),
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "id": id,
    "title": title,
    "description": description,
    "url": url,
    "category": category,
    "random_order": randomOrder,
    "pass_mark": passMark,
    "draft": draft,
    "durationtest": durationtest,
    "get_questions": List<dynamic>.from(getQuestions.map((x) => x.toJson())),
  };
}

class GetQuestion {
  GetQuestion({
    this.id,
    this.content,
    this.getanswers,
  });

  int id;
  String content;
  List<Getanswer> getanswers;

  factory GetQuestion.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => GetQuestion(
    id: json["id"],
    content: json["content"],
    getanswers: List<Getanswer>.from(json["getanswers"].map((x) => Getanswer.fromJson(x))),
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "id": id,
    "content": content,
    "getanswers": List<dynamic>.from(getanswers.map((x) => x.toJson())),
  };
}

class Getanswer {
  Getanswer({
    this.id,
    this.content,
    this.correct,
    this.questionId,
  });

  int id;
  Content content;
  bool correct;
  int questionId;

  factory Getanswer.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Getanswer(
    id: json["id"],
    content: contentValues.map[json["content"]],
    correct: json["correct"],
    questionId: json["question_id"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "id": id,
    "content": contentValues.reverse[content],
    "correct": correct,
    "question_id": questionId,
  };
}

enum Content { A, B, C, D }

final contentValues = EnumValues({
  "A": Content.A,
  "B": Content.B,
  "C": Content.C,
  "D": Content.D
});

class EnumValues<T> {
  Map<String, T> map;
  Map<T, String> reverseMap;

  EnumValues(this.map);

  Map<T, String> get reverse {
    if (reverseMap == null) {
      reverseMap = map.map((k, v) => new MapEntry(v, k));
    }
    return reverseMap;
  }
}
```

When I try to call QuizPlay(), I get the following error

**Error: Could not find the correct Provider above this QuestionTile Widget
This happens because you used a `BuildContext` that does not include the provider
of your choice. There are a few common scenarios:

- You added a new provider in your `main.dart` and performed a hot-reload.
  To fix, perform a hot-restart.
- The provider you are trying to read is in a different route.
  Providers are "scoped". So if you insert of provider inside a route, then
  other routes will not be able to access that provider.
- You used a `BuildContext` that is an ancestor of the provider you are trying to read.
  Make sure that QuestionTile is under your MultiProvider/Provider.
  This usually happens when you are creating a provider and trying to read it immediately.**